# Probability of hitting square inscribed in a circle of radius $r$?

Tags: probability, geometry

In my probability book there was a question of finding the probability of choosing a random point from circle inscribed in circle, which I found out to be $pi$/$4$. After solving this question I thought of its reverse scenerio of the same problem in which square is inside in a circle and I have to find out probability of choosing random point from square inscribed in a circle, this time.

My Calculations so far:\

Let $E$ be the event of choosing point from square.

For square inscribed in a circle with radius $r$ and Area = $\pi r^2$, we have diagonal of square given by: D = $2r$

I can't seem to figure out how do find the area of circle now from this point? because that's the only information I need to find the desired result. i.e: P(E) = Area of square/Area of circle

Comment: Is this actually a probability problem at this point? It seems more like a straight geometry problem: find what fraction of a circle's area is occupied by an inscribed square (e.g. the figure [here](https://ds055uzetaobb.cloudfront.net/brioche/uploads/YebdMMueFz-ukinnam.jpg?width=2400))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagonal of the square is in fact $2r$. Using Pythagoras, the length of the square, $x$, is given by
$$x^2+x^2=4r^2\implies 2x^2=4r^2\implies x^2=2r^2\implies x=r\sqrt2$$
Hence the area of the square is $(r\sqrt 2)^2=2r^2$

Divide the area of the square by the area of the circle and there's your answer.

Comment: I used pythagoras theorem but I was taking $x$ and $y$ as lengths of square, instead of just $x$ since its a square. Anyway, Thanks alot. It helped

Comment: @AmeerShah my pleasure. You may accept this answer if it was very useful if you like :)#